# "Bootstrapping" a remote swf into the application SecurityDomain (actionscript3)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, applicationdomain, securitydomain

My Flash (AS3/AIR) application is currently using a slightly unusual architecture (for a Flash app) to provide particular base classes for loaded content at runtime. The external content is published with 'stub' base classes, which are eclipsed by the 'real' base classes at runtime when it is loaded. I've heard this referred to by Adobe as *bootstrapping* ([pdf](http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/loadingSubApps.pdf)), and it has been working very well for me until now. It's not unlike a DLL architecture I believe, although I'm not qualified to say for sure.

Until now, the external content I have been loading has been loaded from within the same `SecurityDomain` (same sandbox), which allows me to easily load the content in a child `ApplicationDomain`. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, an `ApplicationDomain`s that span `SecurityDomain`s cannot be related - that is, I cannot make an AppDom of one SecurityDom the child of an AppDom from another SecurityDom.

But now I need to load this external content from outside my Application sandbox. There are plenty of ways to achieve communication across `SecurityDomain`s - although most of them are very limited, AIR's `sandboxBridge` API is probably the most powerful. Unfortunately, none of these communication methods allow me to achieve this bootstrapping architecture.

I notice that the `LoaderContext` object has a `securityDomain` property, but Flash security prohibits 'local swfs' from touching it (it throws a `SecurityError` or similar).

Flex's `SWFLoader` has a `trustContent` property that looks promising, but I'm inclined to assume that it has the same restrictions as setting the `SecurityDomain` in the `Loader`'s `LoaderContext`.

I suspect I'll have to redesign (which won't be easy), but I thought I'd just check here that I've not missed something in my research.

So ... any ideas or pearls of wisdom? I'd especially freaking love it if someone from Adobe who works on the Security model could gimme a definitive "yes/no it can/can't be done"...

Thanks in advance!

*Addendum:* I've since decided to re-design the architecture so that the bootstrapping all happens on the external domain. My question still stands, however, out of curiosity.

Comment: what approach did u end up using? :) I posted a somewhat related q here stackoverflow.com/questions/1020397/…, would love to get feedback on it / as it seems u have been working with third party external swf :)

Comment: Freddy, I wonder if my question is a bit out of date now, as I wrote when FP10 was in beta.

Comment: Wow. Over a thousand views and net zero votes. Hah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, I determined that you cannot load an `ApplicationDomain` into your own `SecurityDomain` if it is from another domain, even with AIR.

By design, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, wouldn't it be possible for your AIR application to simply save the external SWFs inside your application directory, and load them from there so that they live in the same security sandbox?

However, there are some really obvious reasons why this would be Bad Karma, so it seems like any solution necessarily raises the question of whether trying to put local application content and remote untrusted content into the same app domain is the right architecture approach..?

Comment: Technically speaking, no: an AIR app can't modify its own application directory. AIR apps have a local storage folder for saving data, but again, that's a separate security domain.

Comment: But yeah, I totally agree about the bad karma thing. The flash security model has been devised by very smart people to enforce a collection of best practices so it is a bit silly to swim against the tide. In my defense, the external domain is "trusted" (w. airquotes) but that's not really the point.

Comment: Ahh... I know there are restrictions to an app modifying its app directory contents but I thought they were overridable. Given that, I don't know if your original aim is possible or not.

Comment: Mmm. I have decided that it is not possible, since I can't find anyone/anything to tell me otherwise. If it is possible, I don't know how, so it's the same outcome either way! Thanks for the answer, fenomas.

Comment: Even if you are able to do it, modifying the app's folder can break other things ... one is the encrypted store, as soon as u touch one of the application files you don't get failures accessing the store.